# PageModel.Page() is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, .net, script, razor-pages

Estou precisando usar um script de um alert() no meu projeto .NET core razor, e quando eu adiciono a linha:

```
Page.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Hello World')", true);
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

> 'PageModel.Page()' is a method, which is not valid in the given
>   context

Me ajudem por favor, não sei como resolver... Já tentei remover o `Page.` e dá o seguinte:

> The name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the current context

E eu não consigo usar o `using System.Web.UI;`

**Método:**

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(PARAMETROS){
      CancellationTokenSource backGroundTask = new CancellationTokenSource();
      MobAtivacaoAcesso MobAtivacaoAcesso = new MobAtivacaoAcesso("X", "Z");

      await MobAtivacaoAcesso.AtivacaoVerificarAsync(PARAMETROS); 

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(MobAtivacaoAcesso.MensagemTemporaria)){
          Response.Headers.Add("mensagem", MobAtivacaoAcesso.MensagemTemporaria);
      }

      return;
}
```

Comment: Afinal, você está com qual tipo de projeto? MVC, WebForms, Razor Pages? qual?

Comment: Não querendo ser grosso, mas está na pergunta... .NET core razor....

Comment: é Razor Pages e o que na pergunta é Web Forms então o que você deseja fazer, porque esse código não funciona em Razor Pages?

Comment: O que deseja fazer com uma função de `alert`? o seu código não funciona

Comment: eu gostaria de fazer o alert de uma mensagem que esta sendo retornada de um metodo

Comment: poste o método?

Comment: Claro, @VirgilioNovic, vou deixar o código na pergunta

Comment: No caso, se eu conseguisse usar o Script, seria no lugar desse `Response.Headers.Add("mensagem", MobAtivacaoAcesso.MensagemTemporaria);`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94061/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-samuel-machado).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ScriptManager era usando tradicionalmente com WebForms e UpdatePanel para realizar requisições ajax e render parciais, no ASP.NET Core você não terá mais isso (acredito que nem será migrado).

No caso, o ASP.NET Core assume em alguns do seus templates a View Engine Razor (Mas sua aplicação poderia ser uma SPA, por exemplo), que possui um markup que te auxiliam no desenvolvimento das paginas em geral. Então seria legal saber o que você realmente precisa.

Para seu cenário atual, pasta adicionar uma section de script e executá-lo no loading da página, ou simplesmente adicionar alguma biblioteca para não mexer diretamente no DOM, como por exemplo, o jquery.

Enfim, você poderia simplesmente fazer isso:

```
@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            alert('Olá!');
        }, false)
    </script>

}
```

Você pode enviar informações para View usando ViewBag, Models, TempData etc...

Controller:

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Mensagem = "Teste Mensagem";
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            alert('@ViewBag.Mensagem'); 
        }, false)
    </script>

}
```

Então é preciso estudar um pouco sobre a tecnologia para ficar familiarizado, sugiro fazer os tutorias para MVC e/ou Razor Pages:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Links sobre razor:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_intro.asp

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/

Comment: Então rafael, eu estou começando a trabalhar com .NET por agora, mas acredito que isso não daria certo, pois o conteúdo do alerta que eu preciso mostrar está no index.cs, dentro de uma variavel string

Comment: Vc precisa colocar o cenário todo na pergunta! Eu melhorei a resposta, é o máximo que eu posso ajudar.